# Customizing fields with the administrate gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, thoughtbot

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to modify the [administrate gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate)'s default dashboards in order to customize what gets displayed in the index and show pages. Here's my specific goal:

- Given that an `Article` `belongs_to` an `Author`
- When I create an Article
- I want to see the Author's last name in the dropdown list for the associated field
- And once saved, I want to see the Author's last name in the Article's index and show pages

Right now, instead, I get a not-so-useful "Author #4" as the record label. Here's the automatically generated dashboard:

```
class ArticleDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    author: Field::BelongsTo,
    id: Field::Number,
    title: Field::String,
    content: Field::Text,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime,
  }.freeze
  [snip]
end
```

The "[Customizing Dashboard](http://administrate-prototype.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards)" documentation page says:

> Each of the Field types take a different set of options, which are specified through the `.with_options` class method.

So I figure that calling `with_options` on `Field::BelongsTo` might be the way to go, but what options are available for that field (or for any other, for that matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In administrate, you may customize how a resource is displayed by overwriting the #display_resource method in the resource's dashboard.

All of your dashboards inherit from Administrate::BaseDashboard, which uses the following method to display resources:

```
def display_resource(resource)
  "#{resource.class} ##{resource.id}"
end
```

You'll want to add something like this to the AuthorDashboard to overwrite the default:

```
def display_resource(author)
  author.last_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks. While this solves the specific problem, I still wonder about what options are available for each field type.